# Running Fitnesse in Debug mode

Tags: fitnesse

I used to use Fitnesse daily years ago, but forgot how to run tests in debug mode (or have stack trace information be output) - does anyone know?

I recall being able to configure it either as a flag when running/starting up fitnesse.jar, or as a URL parameter (e.g. http://localhost:8090/FitLibraryWeb.MyTest?test&debug=true)

Answer (score 3):

To debug fixtures in .Net I normally add Debugger.Break() inside my C# fixture code

Comment: This is the way I have always done it. The problem with trying to attach to a process is that each Fitnesse test kicks off its own Test Runner process.  
If you don't want to always break when running the fixture code in debug mode then you could modify the fixture itself to conditionally break.

Answer (score 2):

Although my prefered development solution has already been pointed out on [Rustin's DebugBreak() suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7754139/378115), and alternate solution is to invoke **RunnerW.exe**, which requires adding the following line to your target Fitnesse test page

```
[[Press me to start in remote debug mode][?responder=test&remote_debug=true]]
```

Please, bear in mind that I am assuming your test page already defines **REMOTE_DEBUG_RUNNER** pointing to **RunnerW.exe**, as stated in [Fitnesse guide's Customizing Test Execution section](http://www.fitnesse.org/FitNesse.FullReferenceGuide.UserGuide.WritingAcceptanceTests.CustomizingTestExecution)

For the sake of simplicity, I will present a sample fit test header.

So, here is how to **Remote Debug using Visual Studio**:

1. Make sure you fitnesse test page starts with the following lines

> ```
> !define TEST_RUNNER {FitSharp\Runner.exe}
>
> !define REMOTE_DEBUG_RUNNER {FitSharp\RunnerW.exe}
>
> [[Press me to start in remote debug mode][?responder=test&remote_debug=true]]
>
> The rest of your test specification goes here
> ```

2. In **Visual Studio**, set target code breakpoint
3. On fit test page, click on **Press me to start in remote debug mode**, defined above. This starts the **RunnerW.exe** process (winform app called **Fitsharp**) which will wait for 30 seconds (I am not sure).
4. In **Visual Studio** > **Debug** menu > **Attach to process**, locate **RunnerW.exe** and press **Attach** button.
5. On **Fitsharp** window (**RunnerW.exe** process), click **GO** button and you are on your way.

As pratical solution, I use the following strategy:

1. I create static page called **SetupEngine** and add the 3 lines stated on previous step 1.
2. **On the top of every test page**, I just put the following header, so I don't have to repeat those 3 lines.

> !include .SetupEngine

Note that **.** (dot) on **.SetupEngine** (which is a path) refers to your Fitnesse root page. You may have to adjust it.

I had this ideia when I was referring to [Fitnesse.UserGuide's remote debug section](http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.WritingAcceptanceTests.DebuggingFixtureCode)

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

Add the following line just before the your test target location

```
!|debug|
```

For further details, refer to [Michael Sorens' excelent article](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/net-tools/acceptance-testing-with-fitnesse-debugging-control-flow-and-tracing/), the most comprehensive article on Fitnesse debug techniques.

Answer (score 1):

Your thinking of using **RunnerW.exe** as opposed to the Runner.exe.

If you change your test runner to be RunnerW a pop-up window will appear with a 'go' button on it, and will not start the fitnesse test until you hit it.

Before hitting go you can attach to any process (via 'Attach To Process' in the debug menu if your using VS) and the execution will pause at the break points set.

**Note**: You must have the same build being used by FitNesse as the code you are debugging.

You can also attach to a remote process, using the Remote Debugger.

Also, if you attach the the RunnerW.exe process, you can debug the fixtures themselves.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had to do it in a while, but the current documentation that comes with FitNesse indicates that you are close.  You should be using **remote_debug** instead of **debug**.

The best thing is to start with the documentation that comes with your copy of FitNesse, as it matches what you are running.  If you are running on port 8080, then the following link should work: http://localhost:8080/FitNesse.UserGuide.DebugingFixtureCode.

Assuming you are using Java, these instructions should help.  If you are using a different language I am not sure I can help.

Comment: Reading the doco, I think remote_debug is only available when running tests on remote wiki, but thanks for the suggestion. My tests just hang but I can clearly see in the test history they passed

Comment: Are you seeing the pass results in the web page or only in the history?  Do you see part of the results or all?

Comment: Only in the history, Dan. All results appear to be there. Might as well close this off, since the tests do appear to (eventually) complete. Why they're taking so long is what has me concerned

Comment: Are you in Java or .Net?  How many tables do you have on the page?  How big are they?  What release of FitNesse?  I know this is off the original topic, but there still might be an answer to the thing that started you wondering how to debug.